# $(inherited) is not working in xcode

Tags: xcode

I notice something wierd in my project.
At project level I have the field Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries set to NO.

In my targets I have set the value $(inherited) for the field Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries.
But when I check the preview of the value in the target is showing the YES - $(inherited). Why?